# Hibernate 3, proxy classes generation does not work fine

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy

I get an issue I don't understand.

I use criteria to find objets. My query return 2 objects in a list.
The returned objects contain attribute with lazy property. They are instance of the class below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5160452300417105888L;

    private Long idDocument;
    private Dossier dossier;
    private DocumentStatut documentStatut;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "Document_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Document_seq_gen", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_DOCUMENT")
    @Column(name = "ID_DOCUMENT", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public Long getIdDocument() {
        return this.idDocument;
    }

    public void setIdDocument(final Long idDocument) {
        this.idDocument = idDocument;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DOSSIER", nullable = false)
    public Dossier getDossier() {
        return this.dossier;
    }

    public void setDossier(final Dossier dossier) {
        this.dossier = dossier;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_STATUT", nullable = false)
    public DocumentStatut getDocumentStatut() {
        return this.documentStatut;
    }

    public void setDocumentStatut(final DocumentStatut documentStatut) {
        this.documentStatut = documentStatut;
    }

}
```

Here DocumentStatut class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT_STATUT")
public class DocumentStatut implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long idStatut;
    private String libStatut;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_STATUT", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public Long getIdStatut() {
        return this.idStatut;
    }

    public void setIdStatut(final Long idStatut) {
        this.idStatut = idStatut;
    }

    @Column(name = "LIB_STATUT", length = 30)
    public String getLibStatut() {
        return this.libStatut;
    }

    public void setLibStatut(final String libStatut) {
        this.libStatut = libStatut;
    }

}
```

The list first element's attribute DocumentStatut is marked as proxy class. I can see thanks to the hander=org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@771d7724 in the instance.

But, and it is my problem, for the second element, attribute DocumentStatut is not marked as proxy class.

Is there anything wrong with hibernate 3?

This is how I retrieve entites

```
   public List<Document> findDocumentsByCriteria(final Long idDossier, final Personne personne, final String codeTypePiece, final List<DocumentStatut> statutDocs) {
        final Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Document.class);
        if (idDossier != null) {
            final Dossier dossier = new Dossier(idDossier);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("dossier", dossier));
        }
        if (personne != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("personne", personne));
        }
        if (codeTypePiece != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("codTypePiece", codeTypePiece));
        }
        if (statutDocs != null && !statutDocs.isEmpty()) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.in("documentStatut", statutDocs));
        }
        final List<Document> listDocuments = criteria.list();
        return listDocuments;
    }
```

I have just arrived on the project. They explain me they have the problem I am trying to describe.

Comment: there is a compilation error afaics... ```this.DocumentStatut = documentStatut;``` should be ```this.documentStatut = documentStatut;```

Comment: by the way, why are you using a so old hibernate version (last release of 3.x branch is almost 6 years old)? have you a good reason? and please show us the definition of the DocumentStatus type, and how you query your db (that's valuable information for any diagnostics)

Comment: what's the actual problem? is it `null` instead of an object or is it just not a proxy? note that it doesn't need to be a proxy, it can be a proxy, but in some cases the object gets loaded directly without a proxy

Comment: You are right about setting documentStatut property. It was a mistake I made when I copied here my class.   Here the DocumentStatut class

Comment: the problem is that for the instance proxy, I get all fields setted, what I want. But for the object got directly, I have only the id attribute setted. When I call document.getDocumentStatut(), It does not update the others fields.

Comment: @user2938679 please don't post code in a comment, edit your question. and show us the way you query the entities

Comment: @spi Sorry :-) I have just edited my question.

Comment: @user2938679 please show us how you retrieve the entities (the part of code that uses entitymanager to load the entities), as the mapping is a good start but far from enough to answer you.

Comment: @spi you have the method findDocumentsByCriteria added in my question.

Comment: I bet that happens only when you restrict the search to at least a given documentStatut? it disappears when the search does not look for any documentStatut, right?

Comment: @spi I don't restrict the search to any given documentStatut. Only the criterias dossier, personne and codeTypePiece are used when I get the problem.

Comment: @spi I forget to say that when I run the same testcase, a few second after without restarting my server, without doing anything before, I get the result I expect

Comment: @ajnfde hum interesting... I don't know what happens, but some hints: 1) turn sql logging on and look closely to the queries, in particular, to every queries called before accessing your code. Probabilities are that somebody elsewhere is half-loading instances of DocumentStatut, that are cached by hibernate and updated only under some conditions. 2) put a breakpoint in the constructor of DocumentStatut to see when it is first instantiated (again, I guess it is a bit too soon and not by the code you expect it). 3) create a test case for this, which reproduce the problem and I could run at home